# Applying Savitzky-Golay filter on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series data set:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2020-07-01', end='2020-07-20', freq='d')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
```

I would like to calculate a Savitzky-Golay filter and a pandas dataframe, which I defined in the following function:

```
def savgol(x, wl=3, p=2):
    return savgol_filter(x, window_length=wl, polyorder=p)

df['sav_gol'] = df['data'].apply(savgol)
```

When executing the script I recieve the following error message:

**ValueError: If mode is 'interp', window_length must be less than or equal to the size of x.**

EDIT:

Here is my adjusted dataset with groups. I would apply the savgol function to this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':date_rng,
    'value':np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng))),
    'group':'a'
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':date_rng,
    'value':np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng))),
    'group':'b'
})

df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

This would be my attempt:

```
df['sav_gol'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(savgol)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to say without sample data.  One guess is that you have fewer than 21 rows in your data set, which is smaller than you window size.

Comment: you're applying the filter row-wise, it gets a single value for each call but it needs at least `wl` items to work, you should probably call `savgol_filter` over the whole column instead without using `apply`. Also you're sample dataset has 20 rows so it still won't work with a 21 long window

Comment: I reduced the window size to 3 and the still get the same error

Comment: see my comment, that's not enough because you're using "apply" row-wise

Comment: `df['sav_gol'] = savgol(df["data"])`

Comment: @filippo, it works, thanks. My intention using apply was to extend the code with groupby function later...I also tried df['sav_gol'] = df['data'].apply(savgol, axis=1), which seems not correct

Comment: it would be great to see a complete example to better understand what you are trying to achieve and how to help you, do you think you could come up with a sample dataset where you can showcase the groupby thing?

Comment: @filippo: I added a sample dataset to the question

Comment: I also tried this: ```df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x: savgol_filter(x, 3,2), axis=1)```, which didnt work either

Comment: Add the savgol_filter function to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually worked:

```
df['savgol'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(lambda x: savgol_filter(x, 5,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This puts the result back in the dataframe and keeps the index:

`df['savgol'] = df[['data']].appy(lambda x: savgol_filter(x,5,2))`